# SSL Handshake Exception when Requesting to a HTTPS URL

Tags: java, android, android-async-http

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:392)

I am using AsyncHttpClient library to make requests.

But I am wondering why is this happening? Any thoughts?

Note: I am using Cloud Flare on my webserver

```
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("https://api.DOMAIN_NAME.id/v1/merchant/auth/check_email_availability", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                System.out.println("STATUS CODE " + statusCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });
```

Comment: You use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: I am using cloud flare on the webserver. And I have no idea what is used. @JörnBuitink